# MoSQL error : Mongd DB 'user' not found in config file. & Skipping op for unknown ns user.info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql, database-migration

I am running mosql as:

```
mosql -c collections.yml --sql postgres://sql-url/sql-db --mongo mongodb://node1,node2,node3/user?replicaSet=rs0 --only-db user --reimport -vvv
```

mongoDB dbs:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin  (empty)
local  0.281GB
test   0.031GB
user   0.031GB
```

and my collections.yml is:

```
user:
 info:
   :columns:
   - id:
     :source: _id
     :type: TEXT
   - first_name: VARCHAR(15)
   - last_name: VARCHAR(15)
   - gender: VARCHAR(6)
   - email: VARCHAR(30)
   - somenumber:
     :source: id
     :type: INTEGER
  :meta:
   :table: user_table
   :extra_props: true
```

I'm getting error:

```
INFO MoSQL: Skipping DB scan and using db: user
INFO MoSQL: Mongd DB 'user' not found in config file. Skipping.
```

and

```
DEBUG MoSQL: Skipping op for unknown ns user.info...
```

Where can I find mosql config file and what should I add in it??

Answer (score 0):

The `.YAML` file I was using was not valid. I parsed it with [yamllint.com](http://yamllint.com) to verify.